# Valueerror: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,2) into shape (2)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, valueerror

I'm writing python code to do finite element analysis and make a stiffness matrix.
It threw this error and I just can't figure out why.

```
def solve_displacement(a, l, E, F):
    import numpy as np
    m = a.size
    n = m + 1
    k = np.zeros((2,2))
    zeros = np.zeros((n,n))
    K = np.copy(zeros)
    for i in range(1,m):
        k[i] = element_stiffness(a[i],l[i],E)
        K[i:i+1,i:i+1] += k[:,:]
    Ks = np.copy(K[2:n,2:n])
    Fs = np.copy(F[2:n])
    d = solve(Ks,Fs)
```

a and l are m vectors and F is an n vector. E is a constant.
This gives me this error.

```
k[i] = element_stiffness(a[i],l[i],E)

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,2) into shape (2)
```

If anyone could point me in a direction, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You are trying to put a 2x2 array (4 elements) into a array slot that only has space for 2. `k` is (2,2), so `k[i]` is (2,).  In the next line `K[i:i+1,i:i+1]` has shape (1,1), but you are trying to add to it a (2,2) array.  Pay close(r) attention to the shape of arrays at each step of your calculation.  Add to debugging prints to verify your guesses.

Comment: How does K[i:i+1,i:i+1] have shape (1,1)? Shouldn’t that always be a 2x2 matrix?

Comment: Nevermind, i think i figured it out, thank you for your help!